# Update IntelliJ environment variables after changes at the OS level

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I updated some environment variables and also the `PATH` value at the operating system level (Windows 10).

I opened a new Command Prompt and everything is fine.

But after restarting IntelliJ IDEA (even with Invalidate Caches option) and I open a Terminal in IntelliJ, the environment variables are still the old ones.

How could I force a refresh of the environment variables in IntelliJ?

Comment: IDE restart should be sufficient. What exactly is the problem? What is the IDE version? What are your Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Terminal options? Try enabling/disabling **Shell integration** and restart IDE.

Comment: The problem is that IntelliJ terminal is not similar to Windows Command Prompt in terms of environment variables. And I want to run commands like `mvn ...`, `java ...`, `javac ...` directly from there.

The IDE version: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.

I'll check the Terminal options + the Shell integration. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to enable / disable + restart and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It looks similar to the outdated issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181561, but does not reproduce on 2019 IDEA version. Have you also tried restarting the computer, not only IDEA?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after computer restart it started to work.